# html javascript class="highslide" not working on android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, highslide

I have simple html web pages where some host a single picture. I am just using this in the html pages:

```
<a href="photo1.png" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
    <img src="photo1.png" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="43%" width="60%" />
</a>
```

Is highslide a javascript code? Should there be reference to it on a separate file such as .css or .js?

Alone in the html file, this works well on computer desktop browsers Firefox, IE, Chrome... but not on android smartphone browsers (currently testing on ICS Native android, Chrome, Dolphin, Opera...).

In order to have this work on android, do I have to amend highslide methods and properties in the css file?

If that doesn't change, how can I amend this code to detect if the user is on android or non-javascript enable or capable browser?

I would like to avoid if possible and not too difficult to supply another html page in case the browser android or else can't manage highslide.

Thanks

Pascal

Answer (score 0):

Highlight is a javascript library.  See here for full documentation: http://highslide.com/

Although this page does not explicitly state that Android is supported, it appears to work on Android.  However there seem to be a few issues.  You would do best by searching the [highslide forums](http://forum.highcharts.com/).  Here is one thread which may help: http://forum.highcharts.com/highslide-js-usage/android-dolphin-hd-browser-tf201-white-box-t15461/

I think you're best bet is to figure out what in your css or js is incompatible with Android and fixing that - not completely disabling highslide or creating a separate android-only page.

Comment: Hi Manishie, new infos as I didn't wait for these to post... I went in some computer and high tech public shops where by chance all devices were connected and I realized by browsing to the site that some (the majority) android device (all tablets) would display the picture and some wouldn't. Windows 8 would display it as well 100%. Some android OS might need updates like mine? A link to the site might help (in construction, nothing else but html... no tracking, analytics...) http://bricabrac.tekcities.com/j1003_msaccessadmInterface.html thanks

Comment: Did you try the solution at the bottom of the post I linked to?

Comment: Hi, long delay, busy with work and flu... your link is mainly about Android Dolphin browser app. I'm looking for a general understanding of this and fix where it's not working. I think it's specific to some devices that didn't get the last Android update. thanks

Comment: The question was specific to the Dolphin browser but the response address the fact that there are general Android issues that can be solved with their suggestions (not browser specific issues)